# FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO with my private class AutoFocusCallback

Tags: android, camera, focus, continuous

I have a problem, I'm making an application using the camera and need to know when the autofocus is activated. Use the setFocusMode (Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO) and I created a private class AutoFocusCallBackImpl with the method **onAutoFocus (boolean success, Camera camera)** but it is never called. As [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO) it should be called. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Before API 14, your callback is not called in this mode at all. You don't need to; the device is (trying to keep the image) always in focus. From API 14, you can call `autoFocus()` and it will call back to indicate whether it considers the image in focus now.